# Identify minifig head with large glasses and grey torso with red hands?

Tags: minifigures, minifigure-identification

I'm sure that this body is the original LEGO. But I'm not sure with head.

What parts are these and which set did they come from?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Torso is [973pb0048c01 : Torso Aquazone Stingray Dark Turquoise, Black, and Gold Pattern 1 / Dark Gray Arms / Red Hands](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=973pb0048c01#T=C&C=10)

appears in [4](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=973pb0048c01&in=S) Aquazone sets from 1998

Answer (score 3):

The head is proper LEGO too: [3626bpb0126 Minifigure, Head Female Glasses with Orange Goggles, Dimples around Lips Pattern - Blocked Open Stud](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3626bpb0126&name=Minifigure,%20Head%20Female%20Glasses%20with%20Orange%20Goggles,%20Dimples%20around%20Lips%20Pattern%20-%20Blocked%20Open%20Stud&category=%5BMinifigure,%20Head%5D#T=S&C=3&O=%7B%22color%22:3,%22iconly%22:0%7D)

This head appeared in [4 sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3626bpb0126&in=S), all from 2002-2003

I haven’t been able to identify the torso yet though ....

Comment: Thank you. It's weird because I don't have any of these sets. Only this head.